# $\log \cosh \pi y =\pi y - \log 2+ \epsilon_2(y)$ with $\epsilon_2(y)$ tending to $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I was reading Ahlfors's Complex Analysis Section 5.2.5; Stirling's formula. There are two parts that I can't justify:

1. Developing the logarithm in a Taylor series we find

$iy \log$$1/2+iy \over 1/2-iy$$=iy(\pi i+\log$$1+1/2iy \over 1-1/2iy$$)=-\pi y+1+\epsilon_1(y)$

with $\epsilon_1(y)$ tending to $0$. (Here $y$ is real.)

2. $\log \cosh \pi y =\pi y - \log 2+ \epsilon_2(y)$ with $\epsilon_2(y)$ tending to $0$.

How do I have to justify these?

(The "$\log$" above is the principal branch of logarithm.)

Comment: The hyperbolic cosine of $t$ is $(e^t+e^{-t})/2$, rewrite as $(e^t/2)(1+e^{-2t})$, so its log is $t-\log2+\log(1+e^{-2t})$, from which (2) follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first, $\log(\frac{1+z}{1-z})$ has a taylor series $2z+2z^3/3 +\cdots$ about $z=0$ In particular, with $z=\frac{1}{2iy}$, we get the desired result, with $\epsilon_1(y) = O(y^{-2})$.
For the second, the comment by @ Gerry Myerson works: $\cosh(z) = \frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2} = \frac{e^z(1+e^{-2z})}{2}$ so $\log(\cosh \pi y) = \pi y -  \log 2 + log(1+e^{-2\pi y})$, and let $\epsilon_2(y) = \log(1+e^{-2\pi y})$